# Django rest framewrok how to query relationalship

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
models.py

class Employee(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50 )
    Email = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name              # __unicode__ on Python 2



class EmployeeProfile(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='fromemployee')
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    employeesomething= models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='refirence')

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
       return self.Address



serializers.py

class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('id', 'Name')


class EmployeeProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    # usergroups = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    employee_set = EmployeeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeProfile
        fields = ('id', 'Address','employee','job_title','employeesomething','employee_set')


views.py

class EmployeeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmployeeSerializer    

class EmployeeProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = EmployeeProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmployeeProfileSerializer        


urls.py

router = routers.DefaultRouter()


router.register(r'employee', views.EmployeeViewSet)
router.register(r'employeeprofile', views.EmployeeProfileViewSet)


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]


my out put   http://localhost:8000/employeeprofile/
```

```js
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "Address": "Hyderabd",
        "employee": "localhost:8000/employee/1/",
        "job_title": "admin",
        "employeesomething": "http://localhost:8000/employee/2/"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "Address": "Hyderabd",
        "employee": "http://localhost:8000/employee/1/",
        "job_title": "admin",
        "employeesomething": "http://localhost:8000/employee/3/"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "Address": "Hyderabd",
        "employee": "http://localhost:8000/employee/4/",
        "job_title": "admin",
        "employeesomething": "http://localhost:8000/employee/5/"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "Address": "Hyderabd",
        "employee": "http://localhost:8000/employee/4/",
        "job_title": "admin",
        "employeesomething": "http://localhost:8000/employee/6/"
    }
]
```

*
    There is relation between Employee and EmployeeProfile if i pass Employe Id i need get Employee Profile how to query Please help me.And is it passbul to use viewsets.ModelViewSet to get query Thanks 
    *

Comment: If you want the `EmployeeProfile` instead of its link, use `ModelSerializer`, not `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I want to write a filter when i pass a Employee id i need a EmpoyeeProfile that associated with Employee in my case employee 1 is in EmpoyeeProfile 1,2 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view:

Let's say you get `employee_id` in your `request.data`

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from myapp.serializers import EmployeeProfileSerializer
from myapp.models import EmployeeProfile


class MyView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, *arga, **kwargs)
        e_profiles = EmployeeProfile.objects.filter(employee__pk=request.GET.get('employee_id'))

        # Then call you serializer

        e_serialized = EmployeeProfileSerializer(e_profiles, many=True)
        return Response(e_serialized.data)
```

Comment: What else do you need to understand this? you need to use this code in your view, how are you sending 'employee id' to the view?

Comment: I am new to Rest Framewrok Can you be more can you be More Explicit . I got a name 'request' is not defined error .Thanks you

Comment: You are sending a GET or POST method?

Comment: I am using GET method

Comment: @thisisms I edited the answer. I hope this give you a better idea.

Comment: I am useing ViewSet in my urls i need to change urls ?

Comment: The only thing you need to do is query your model to retrieve only the EmproyeeProfiles objects that match your Emproyee id, and then use that QuerySet to serialize your data.

Comment: Thanks you for help its really help full. I think i miss the basics the documentation is so confusing. Any way Thank you one again

Comment: Can you give me any reference to the documentation ?

Comment: Here you have an example for query in a View with DRF: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/ And here is the Django ORM docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/

Comment: Hi @Gocht  I have a small doubt about. where can i pass the employee id get EmployeeProfile associated with that Employee is in urls or. I am using browsebull API I have no idea what to
do.  here can i create a new Serializer for this result. Please Help me

Comment: @thisisms Your current problem is not clear for me now, please post another question, or please, give me more details.

Comment: I have added your code into my views.py file and create url for that view its give me an empty arry. i need a some input button to post employee id and get the EmployeeProfile
that associated with that Employee . And mention that ("The only thing you need to do is query your model to retrieve only the EmproyeeProfiles objects that match your Emproyee id, and then use that QuerySet to serialize your data")
can you give me an idea how to do that ?

Comment: Since you're using get, you need to pass the Employee id in your url query: .../api/youroath/?employee_id=1

Comment: I still got a empty arry . can you see my code is there anything wrong with that  https://github.com/thisismsreddy/Employee_Testing

Comment: Give me the lines and file. I can't explore all your code.

Comment: And how are you calling your url?

Comment: But your params, I need the full url you are writing in your browser when you call to .../friends

Comment: http://localhost:8000/friends/?employee_id=1/   this is the full url. Did i need to pass any query ?

Comment: I edited the answer, that was my fault, sorry I usually work with POST requests. I changed `request.data.get` by `request.GET.get`

Comment: Try with: `employee__pk=int(request.GET.get('employee_id'))`

Comment: my bad is working i pass the / in url that's why i got error

Comment: My name is Gocht, like my Nickname